# _tk Wordpress Theme: How to add a custom menu item like a button and search form?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, hook

http://themekraft.com/tk-wordpress-bootstrap-starter-theme/

I'm trying to customize _tk theme for wordpress, and I'm currently stuck on the Nav Menu part of it. Menu items can be added from Wordpress admin page so custom links and pages are no problem. But I want to add both a custom button and a search form in the Navigation Menu.

I've been trying to look at the functions.php as well as the header.php but I can't see how to include a menu item inside the .

I've seen others do these, so I think it might be some sort of hook to include a custom menu item. Anyone have an idea on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML code in the title of the menu item

if it's not enough, you can use the filter `wp_get_nav_menu_items`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_nav_menu_items/

example :

```
add_filter("wp_get_nav_menu_items", function ($items, $menu, $args) {

    if (is_admin()) {
        return $items;
    }


    $e = new \stdClass();

    $e->title = "test title " . mt_rand();
    $e->url = "/test_url";
    $e->menu_order = 500;
    $e->post_type = "nav_menu_item";
    $e->type = "custom";
    $e->object = "custom";
    $e->object_id = 0;
    $e->db_id = 0;
    $e->menu_item_parent = 0;
    $e->ID = 0;
    $e->classes = ""; // CSS classes

    $items[] = $e;


    return $items;
}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not well-versed with wordpress, how do I use it to add a custom menu item?